# Android- save my current location with voice command or max 3 clicks

Tags: maps, geo-location, navigation

In my spare time I look for the best car and motorcycle routes and share them with the community. I often test routes that look promising on the map, but in reality are terrible.

I would like to be able to save the location of these best routes without any problems while driving. The best option would be to say "Ok Google, save my current location". However, if it is not possible at the moment, it would also be acceptable to switch to the background application, click the big "Save my location" button and return to navigation. Separate button to be connected by BT? Why not, I am open to solutions.

Can you recommend me a working solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the automation tools like ifttt, tasker, macrodroid, etc... it is very doable. You can set up tasker to record your location to a google sheet based on a number of different triggers.